# Long UIDs create issues with some UNIX commands

Tags: uid

We have users with long UIDs from Active Directory.  I just noticed today that a 'ps aux' shows the UID and not the user name.  Likewise, 'who' does not see the users at all.  On the other hand, an "ls -l" works fine.

An example of a long UID: 200148259

Any ideas, suggestions, pointers?

The OS is CentOS 6.7
The shell is bash 4.1.2